# Configure Symfony to display Exceptions in New Relic

Tags: symfony, newrelic

I'm using New Relic monitor my apps and I have a problem with Symfony: errors are not listed. I don't have the problem with Laravel based application.

I try to specify in `newrelic.ini` the `newrelic.framework` parameter with `symfony`, but nothing.

Is there anything to configure in Symfony, New Relic or the server to make NR detected errors ?

Thanks

Comment: How did you integrate New Relic in your application? Can you show some code/configuration?

Comment: I just have the daemon install and running on the server that's it. Because I can see `web` and `database` transaction in New Relic I suppose this part is fine.

Comment: see https://github.com/ekino/EkinoNewRelicBundle

Comment: So I have to manually push my exceptions to NR ? Laravel does it automatically